# Clear single svg before loading new graph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added multiple graphs on a single JSP page hence this JSP page contains multiple svg elements.

Here is code structure:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
  <div id="placeholder33" style="height: 160px; display: none" class="demo-placeholder">
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <div id="canvas_dahs3" class="demo-placeholder" style="width: 100%; height:270px;">
           <svg></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I am trying to clear only one svg element to load new graph using.

```
d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
```

It removes all svg elements. How can I clear only one svg so that other graphs remains same.

Comment: increase the specificity of that querySelector

Comment: You have an extra `</div>` in there

Comment: yes id =  "canvas_dahs3" is unique for each svg.  but how can I add this condition in  d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use an ID?

```
d3.selectAll("#divID svg > *").remove();
```